# Symfony2 collection persist unique Objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to save a form through a collection in a ManyToMany relationship, the problem is that persist an object!

```
class Anagrafica
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SubCategories", inversedBy="anagrafiche", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="AnCat")
 **/
private $subCategories;

//..
public function __construct()
{
$this->subCategories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
//..
}

/**
 * Add subCategories
 *
 * @param \My\BusinessBundle\Entity\SubCategories $subCategories
 * @return Anagrafica
 */
public function addSubCategory(\My\BusinessBundle\Entity\SubCategories $subCategories)
{
    $subCategories->addAnagrafiche($this);
    $this->subCategories[] = $subCategories;
}

*******
class SubCategories
{
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Anagrafica", mappedBy="subCategories")
 */
private $anagrafiche;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->anagrafiche = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add anagrafiche
 *
 * @param \My\BusinessBundle\Entity\Anagrafica $anagrafiche
 * @return SubCategories
 */
public function addAnagrafiche(\My\BusinessBundle\Entity\Anagrafica $anagrafiche)
{
    $this->anagrafiche[] = $anagrafiche;
}
```

AnagraficaType:

```
//..
->add('subCategories', 'collection', array('type' => new SubCategoriesType(), 
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'prototype_name' => '__categ__',
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
```

when I go to save even if I select a subcategory already exists in the database, he performs a query insert:

```
INSERT INTO SubCategories (subCategory, category_id) VALUES (?, ?)
Parameters: { 1: Object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection), 2: 12 }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you **have** to check manually if a subcategory exists when persisting. You can use a `datatransformer` or put the checking code right in the `addSubCategory` method of your entity or even use `prePresist` lifecycle callback. The logic is following: you get all existing subcategories, and then loop through the entered subcategories. If subcategory has found in your existing subcategories, you add to the result ArrayCollection an existing entity instead of pass the entered *new* subcategory. Here is an example code I used in my projects for the same task with tags:

```
$existingSubcategories = $repository->findAll();

if (count($existingSubcategories) < 1)
    return $enteredSubcategories;

$resultCollection = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

foreach ($enteredSubcategories as $enteredSubcategory)
{
    $exists = false;
    foreach ($existingSubcategories as $existingSubcategory)
    {
        // compare them by any unique param
        if ($existingSubcategory->getName() == $enteredSubcategory->getName())
        {
            $exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $resultCollection[] = ($exists === true) ? $existingSubcategory : $enteredSubcategory;
}

return $resultCollection;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but if I wanted to put it in a datatransformer to be able to reuse, where should I put this code? In the method reverseTransform()?

Comment: Exactly in your case I'd actually suggest to put that in the `addSubCategory` method or even in PrePersist lifecycle callback. Why? Because datatransformer usually used for convert one data representation to another. But if you want to use datatransformer — yes, this code belongs to reverseTransform. Read more about datatransformers here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html and about lifecycle callbacks here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: Thank you, this line not function: `$existingSubcategories = $repository->findAll();`, is incomplete?

Comment: You should understand, this is just an example. You can't just copy and paste it to your project. This site is not a place where you can get the work done for you. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: And yes, `$repository` should be a repository class for `SubCategories antity`

Comment: What you asked after my answer could be found in symfony documentation. Just read it deepper. Good luck!